# iPhone UI internationalization

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, internationalization

When I do translation for web apps, usually I have a script that extracts the strings from the code to a .po file that then I give to the translator, and he has a neat tool that allows him to easily translate all the strings.

On iPhone, is kind of the same thing with the *Localizable.strings* when it comes to strings in the .m files.

My question is: for translating the UI (the XIB files), my translator will have to have a Mac in order to edit the XIBs or is there a way to extract all the string neatly out of the XIB into a more friendly file format ?

I'm thinking on re-initializing all the XIB elements that have string in viewDidLoad but looks to me like overkill ...

Comment: There's no other way than to create IBOutlets for each control and set the text for them by coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen ppl use ibtool. [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002138-BBCBFFDF) might help you.

Comment: Thank you. This got me started in the good direction. For a better tutorial on using the ibtool, one may also want to check this: http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/